# Finding all normal subgroups of $S_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find all normal subgroups of $S_3 \times \mathbb Z_3$.

What's the method of doing this? Anything about direct products I should know?

Comment: It seems rather straightforward that if $H\triangleleft S_3\times\mathbb Z_3$, then $H\cap (S_3\times\{0\})\triangleleft S_3\times\{0\}$. If you know what are normal subgroups of $S_3$, this gives you at least some information about the part of any normal subgroup $H$ of the product, which has zero second coordinate. Maybe with this information about $H$ you could proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_3\times\mathbb Z_3$ is isomorphic to $S_3\oplus\mathbb Z_3$.

Now suppose, H is a subgroup of $S_3$ and K is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_3$. Then $H\oplus K$ is a subgroup of $S_3\oplus\mathbb Z_3$.

Clearly, any subgroup K is normal in $Z_3$.
Take H to be any subgroup normal in $S_3$.

If the above conditions are satisfied, then $H\oplus K$ is normal in $S_3\oplus\mathbb Z_3$

Though, I think there might be more normal subgroups. (I have not yet deeply studied the part)